# Getting error while creating issue with JIRA REST API

Tags: curl, jira-rest-api, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to create an issue using the JIRA API, I am trying to POST this using curl:

```
curl -D- -u username:password -X POST --data filename.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://<JIRA_BASEURL>/rest/api/2/issue/
```

with this data in filename.txt:

```
{
"fields": {
   "project":
   { 
      "key": "PROJECT-key"
   },
   "summary": "REST EXAMPLE",
   "description": "Creating an issue via REST API",
   "issuetype": {
      "name": "Bug"
   }
  }
}
```

And I am getting an error that I am not able to understand

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 03 May 2016 09:57:03 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-AREQUESTID: 174x4470x1
X-ASEN: SEN-34722393
X-Seraph-LoginReason: OUT
X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK
X-ASESSIONID: jhs5ewrt4bh
X-AUSERNAME: username
X-ATENANT-ID: jira.atlassian.net
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=41A2A4ABC78BDABCA7B13FB45E3; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: studio.crowd.tokenkey=""; Domain=.jira.atlassian.net; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: studio.crowd.tokenkey=65IUtfdCjefQ8UlVlh00; Domain=.jira.atlassian.net; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=BLSG-CYWX-OPRE-Y0WF|e3453a213679767e6370dt637e97f58|lin; Path=/; Secure

{"errorMessages":["Unrecognized token 'fieaett': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@fb9e08; line: 1, column: 26]"]}
```

can anyone help me through this please?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

command

```
curl -D- -u username:password -X POST --data-binary "@filename.txt" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://<JIRA_BASEURL>/rest/api/2/issue/
```

filename.txt:

```
{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       { 
          "key": "TEST"
       },
       "summary": "REST ye merry.",
       "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
       }
   }
}
```

This works :)